# Size for Doubly Circular Linked List

Tags: java

I want to know that how to find the last node of a doubly circular linked list in Java, as I want to find the size or number of nodes in a circular linked list.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getSize() {
    int count = 0;
    if (head == null)
        return count;
    else {
        Node temp = head;
        do {
            temp = temp.getNextNode();
            count++;
        } while (temp != head);
    }
    return count;
}
```