# I need help making the int size(); method for a Circularly linked list in Java. This is what I have tried. Is it true?

Tags: java, circular-list

```
public int size(){
    node n = head;
    node m = tail;
    int size = 0;
    While(n!=m){
        size++;
        n=n.getNext();
        }
    return size;
    }
```

Is this code correct? I'm not so sure and I'm asking for you guys opinion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size for Doubly Circular Linked List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30970211/size-for-doubly-circular-linked-list)

Comment: You could have written some unit tests to see if this method was working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code logic is that you never check the last element of the list. Therefore, your `method` will return the number of elements of the linked list minus one. To fix this, initialize `size` to 1 instead of 0. And if you're concerned about linked lists of size 0, then use an if statement to check if the head or tail is null. Here's what it should look like,

```
public int size(){
    node n = head;
    node m = tail;
    if(n == null){
        return 0;
    }
    int size = 1;
    While(n!=m){
        size++;
        n=n.getNext();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: @MohdHafiz For singularly linked lists it's less necessary to set size equal to 1 because you can change the while loop condition to `while(n != null)` and have size start at 0. The loop body would stay the same. And in that case you don't need to check for an empty linked list.

Comment: If I make a size() 'method' for the Singularly Linked List 'class' . Is size need to be equalize to 1 too?

    public int size(){
        int size = 1;
        for(Node n=head; n.next != null; n=n.next)
            size++;
        return size;
    }

Is this code true?

Comment: @MohdHafiz change `n.next != null` to `n != null` and `int size = 1` to `int size = 0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help sir!

Comment: @MohdHafiz Anytime! If you found the answer helpful don't forget to upvote or accept the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Oh by the way, I'm trying to make a DoublyLinkedList `class` too. Would you mind checking it for me?

Comment: 'public int size(){
    Node n = header.getNext();
    Node m = trailer.getPrev();
    if(n == null){
        return 0;
    }
    int size = 1;
    while(n != m){
        size++;
        n = n.getNext();
        }
    return size;
}

Comment: @MohdHafiz is this a circular or noncircular doublylinkedlist?

Comment: `Noncircular` doublylinkedlist

Comment: @MohdHafiz if it's noncircular then the size method is the same as the one for the single linkedlist.

Comment: And how about if it's a `circular` `doublylinkedlist` sir?

Comment: if it's a circular doubly linked list then the size method will be the same as the one for a circular singly linked list. It's not the singly or doubly that affects the size method implementation, rather, the circular vs noncircular that does. The reason is how you traverse each list. In noncircular lists you kept going from the head to null while in circular lists you kept going from the head to the tail.

Comment: Well explained sir! I've learnt a lot. Thank you for your time and kindness :)

Answer (score 0):

No this code is not correct. It will return the size one less than the actual size. The while loop will stop working as soon as condition n!=m is false. This will result in incorrect size. So I suggest you start either as int size=1; or you can do size++ once before you return, outside the while block

Answer (score 0):

Your code will return size less than actual size , i.e. say your Head and Tail are pointing on same node which means you have only one node in list. Your code returns 0 where someone would accept 1.

```
do{
//your stuff
} while();
```

this should work.